# What’s the difference between?

Tags: acid-base

In my exam paper, I got this question:

> Give the name of the fourth member of the homologous series of carboxylic acids.

My answer was **butanoic acid**, but the answer was **butyric acid**. What’s the difference?

Comment: I have impression you have not really bothered yourself even with quick search. Why should then others put any effort to answering, if the ready to be read answers are easy to get ? Hint:  Ethanoic vs acetic acid.

Comment: Now you’re saying ethanoic acid and acetic acid are the same thing ??

Comment: @Googagaman. what we’re saying is a quick search would show you the answer to that

Comment: Oh.............

Comment: @Goo gaga man. Many long known compounds have older legacy empirical name and a newer systematic name recommended by IUPAC. Homologous acid serie is the typical example. Searching for one usually provides the other as well. In the lab or applied chemistry, empiric names are often preferred in "real life" of chemists, as they have tradition, even if harder to remember, as they cannot be ( usually ) derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Butyric acid **also known under the systematic name butanoic acid** is a carboxylic acid with the structural formula $\ce{CH3CH2CH2COOH}$

<sub>[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyric_acid)</sub>

So butanoic acid and butyric acid are the same substance.